# Comment form not submitting and saving comments anymore

Tags: python, django

> I am a newbie in django following a question and answer website tutorial. After loading the comment form and adding a few comments with it, I added a form for adding more answers to the same question in the details.html file and the comment form stopped submitting & saving comments.
> I'm not getting any error except:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

> I after logging, I got the following error logs:

```
DEBUG 2021-04-07 10:48:25,270 utils 17624 1040 (0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "main_comment" WHERE "main_comment"."answer_id" = 12; args=(12,)
DEBUG 2021-04-07 10:48:25,272 utils 17624 1040 (0.000) SELECT "main_comment"."id", "main_comment"."answer_id", "main_comment"."user_id", "main_comment"."comment", "main_comment"."add_time" FROM "main_comment" WHERE "main_comment"."answer_id" = 12; args=(12,)
INFO 2021-04-07 10:48:25,277 basehttp 17624 1040 "GET /detail/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 9643
WARNING 2021-04-07 10:48:25,469 basehttp 17624 1040 "GET /static/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1689
DEBUG 2021-04-07 10:48:37,751 utils 17624 7732 (0.000) SELECT "main_question"."id", "main_question"."user_id", "main_question"."title", "main_question"."details", "main_question"."tags", "main_question"."add_time" FROM "main_question" WHERE "main_question"."id" = 4 LIMIT 21; args=(4,)
DEBUG 2021-04-07 10:48:37,756 base 17624 7732 Exception while resolving variable 'detail' in template 'detail.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'Question' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'detail'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'detail'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 848, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [detail] in <Question: If I had only one statement and wanted to review the overall health of a company, which statement would I use and why?>
```

> Here's my code:

**detail.html (comment section)**

```
<!-- Comment Section Start -->
                <div class="container">
                <h3 class="my-2">Comment</h3>
                <div class="comment-wrapper-{{answer.id}}">
                {% for comment in answer.comment_set.all %}
                <div class="card my-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>
                            {{comment.comment}}
                        </p>
                        <P>
                            <a href="#">{{comment.user.username}}</a>
                        </P>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <!-- Comment Form -->
                <div class="card">
                    <h6 class="card-header">Add Comment</h6>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <textarea class="form-control comment-text-{{answer.id}}"></textarea>
                        <button type="button" data-answer="{{answer.id}}" class="btn btn-dark my-3 save-comment">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %} 
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% for msg in messages %}
            <p class="text-success">{{msg}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                {{answerform.as_table}}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div> 
 <script src="{% static 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".save-comment").on('click',function(){
             var _answerid=$(this).data('answer');
             var _comment=$(".comment-text"+_answerid).val();
             // Ajax
             $.ajax({
                 url:"/save-comment",
                 type:"post",
                 data:{
                     comment:_comment,
                     answerid:_answerid,
                     csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}"
                 },
                 dataType:'json',
                 beforeSend:function(){
                     $(".save-comment").addClass('disabled').text('saving...');
                 },
                 success:function(res){
                     if(res.bool==true){
                        $(".comment-text"+_answerid).val('');
                        // Append Element
                        var _html='<div class="card mb-2 animate__animated animate__bounce">\
                        <div class="card-body">\
                            <p>'+_comment+'</p>\
                            <P>\
                                <a href="#">{{request.user}}</a>\
                            </P>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>';
                    $(".comment-wrapper-"+_answerid).append(_html);
                    var prevCount=$(".comment-count-"+_answerid).text();
                    $(".comment-count-"+_answerid).text(parseInt(prevCount)+1);
                     }
                    $(".save-comment").removeClass('disabled').text('Submit');
                 }
             });
         });
        });
```

**Views.py**

```
#Detail
def detail(request,id):
    quest=Question.objects.get(pk=id)
    tags=quest.tags.split(',')
    answers=Answer.objects.filter(question=quest)
    answerform=AnswerForm
    if request.method=='POST':
        answerData=AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if answerData.is_valid():
            answer=answerData.save(commit=False)
            answer.question=quest
            answer.user=request.user
            answer.save()
            messages.success(request,'Answer has been submitted.')
    return render(request,'detail.html',{
        'quest':quest,
        'tags':tags,
        'answers':answers,
        'answerform':answerform,
    })

# Save Comment
def save_comment(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        comment=request.POST['comment']
        answerid=request.POST['answerid']
        answer=Answer.objects.get(pk=answerid)
        user=request.user
        Comment.objects.create(
            answer=answer,
            comment=comment,
            user=user
        )
        return JsonResponse({'bool':True})

# Save Upvote
def save_upvote(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        answerid=request.POST['answerid']
        answer=Answer.objects.get(pk=answerid)
        user=request.user
        check=UpVote.objects.filter(answer=answer,user=user).count()
        if check > 0: 
            return JsonResponse({'bool':False})
        else:
            Upvote.objects.create(
                answer=answer,
                user=user
        )
            return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
```

> I also tried using JSHint.com to search for and correct possible errors in the js code because i used ajax in saving thecomments.